# why an empty file has 3 bytes

Tags: file

I used Animex to generate a dae file, but when opening in chrome, it is not formatted. So I delete all the content in the dae file using notepad, and it shows that the size of the file is 3 bytes rather than 0, I tried many ways but could not find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [UTF8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). Don't use a text editor to modify files that aren't text.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any way to see it?